# How to write CSS inline with django variable?

Tags: html, css, django

I created a progress bar with bootstrap. Which is where there is a `style` attribute to set the progress width. I linked the progress to the models to retrieve the value. As follows.

```
{% for k in kelas %}
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="progres">
         <div class="kelas mb-2">{{ k.namaKelas }}</div>
         <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style='width:{{k.get_percent}}%' aria-valuenow="{{ k.get_percent }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{ k.get_percent }}%</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But at this point `style='width:{{k.get_percent}}%'` no response on progress width. And in html file it show red color because there is a code that is considered wrong.

How can i get a variable to include django in that style?

Comment: what is the value of `{{k.get_percent}}`

Comment: a number indicating the number of data in the field status=True

Comment: check whether you are getting correct number there.

Answer (score 0):

i have done the same thing, but it worked for me !

```
<div class="progress" style="height: 30px;">
    <div class="progress-bar  bg-info " role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"
        style="width: {{data.type_n}}%">
        <h4>{{data.type_n}}% </h4>
    </div>
</div><br>
```

Comment: Where's the difference bro?